# Unity Photon: Instantiate non-prefab objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

Can somebody tell me whether it is possible to instantiate a non - prefab object in a photon network?
I have some objects created in runtime and I want to sync them by photon network.
Please help me!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nah I don't think so. since photon is only instantiate prefabs from the resource folder. But maybe if you created same object on all player via passing info. through photon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RPCs and RaiseEvent](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/rpcsandraiseevent) and then [manually allocate](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/v2/gameplay/instantiation#manual_instantiation) photonView on object. In my project I using RaiseEvents and custom data and position controllers that allow me to spawn and sync more than 999 objects ([photonView count restriction](https://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/4687/expanding-999-limit-for-photonview)) and sync data only on demand, in this case, you need to share between users some guid and store this in controllers to find this in list or dictionary of spawned objects.